# in MySQL Command Line, how do I paste from the clipboard using only the keyboard?

Tags: mysql, windows-7, paste

Hi I'm learning MySQL using MySQL Workbench Command Line Client v 5.6 in Windows 7.

I type my commands into a text editor, then from the text edtor I copy them onto the clipboard. To paste them into the Command Line Client (CLC) I must right click with the mouse and go to "paste" in the context menu.

I would like to forgo the mouse entirely. But in the CLC, none of the Windows keyboard shortcuts seem to work. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for example produces "^v" while <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd> does nothing.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for "paste"?

Comment: It's difficult to see how this is a programming question.

Comment: On this page you can find the shortkeys for MySQL Workbench. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-keys.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although this question is clearly not a programming question this a way you can do this.

First you start by selecting the window with the command line. This can be done by <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>. Then when the command line windows is active you can paste the content of your clipboard with: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> Then go trough the menu with <kbd>e</kbd> and then <kbd>p</kbd>. The letters will dependent on the language from your windows OS.

Comment: Mr. Radical, you are indeed Radical! Thank you for answering my question.

I apologize for it not being a programming question. I'm inexperienced in programming generally and thought it would qualify as such when I posted it.

Comment: I don't see how this ISN'T one. Help regarding programming tools counts! SQL is used a lot by programmers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Win 10, you can turn on <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> shortcuts to work in the command prompt:

[image: Windows 10 Copy/Paste in Cmd]

Comment: To find this menu open a command prompt instance, and right click on the top bar, near where the X is

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else was trying to paste the password directly into the MySQL "Enter password" prompt, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>